# Does not exist column when creating postgresql function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I try to create a dynamic function that exports data specific ids controlled by a for, but when I run the function it shows me the error that there is no column `i` ,
I would like to concatenate the variable i with the name of the output file

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mifuncion() RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..5 LOOP
    copy (select nombre,dni,edad from test where id=i) TO 'C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\user'+i+'.csv' WITH  CSV HEADER;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COPY doesn't support query parameters, so you can't use PL/PGSQL variables with COPY.
You should use dynamic SQL with EXECUTE instead. You could declare variables to store query statement and file path, and then execute it like this

```
EXECUTE FORMAT('COPY (%s) TO %L WITH CSV HEADER', your_query, file_path);
```

OR

```
EXECUTE FORMAT('COPY (%s) TO %L WITH CSV HEADER', 'SELECT nombre, dni, edad FROM test WHERE id = ' || i, 'C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\user' || i || '.csv');
```

Comment: Could you tell me how I concatenate my query with the execute? Because when I do it gives me error  `EXECUTE FORMAT('COPY (%L) TO %L WITH CSV HEADER',select nombre,dni,edad from test where id=i, 'C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\user'+i+'.csv');`

Answer (score 0):

You could use dynamic SQL with EXECUTE instead,like this

```
statement :='COPY (select nombre,dni,edad from test where id=' || i || ') to ''C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\user' || i ||'.csv''';
EXECUTE statement;
```